# Ruby On Rails self join associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have two tables, and four models in my application. First model is company and it has companies table. Other models are employee,driver and supervisor. I've used single table inheritance in my application.

Company model:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :employees

end
```

And table structure

```
ID   NAME
1    XXX company
```

And Employee, Driver and Supervisor models:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :company

end

class Chef < Employee


end

class Driver < Employee


end

class Supervisor < Employee


end
```

And Employees table structure:

```
ID NAME    COMPANY_ID TYPE
1  Jo      1          Supervisor
2  Jack    1          Driver
3  William 1          Driver
4  Avarell 1          Driver
5  Sam     1          Chef
```

What I need to do is that I want supervisors to access all drivers that belong to same company via a has_many assocations.

I have tried the following piece of code in supervisor class:

```
has_many :drivers, ->(supervisor) {where(company: supervisor.company)}
```

However, rails create the following sql and it is not what I'm expecting

```
SELECT `employees`.* FROM `employees` WHERE `employees`.`type` IN ('Driver') AND `employees`.`supervisor_id` = 4 AND `employees`.`type` IN ('Driver', 'Supervisor') AND `employees`.`company_id` = 1
```

I want rails to create such query while it's building the assocation.

```
SELECT `employees`.* FROM `employees` WHERE `employees`.`type` IN ('Driver') AND `employees`.`company_id` = 1
```

Any suggesstions,

Thanks.

Comment: does a `Driver` `has_one :supervisor`? Or does that association not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `has_many :through` through a `belongs_to` association.

For example this will allow you to access a `Supervisor`'s `drivers` and `chefs` from the same company. You will not be able to go backwards and find a `Driver`'s `supervisor`.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end

class Chef < Employee
end

class Driver < Employee
end

class Supervisor < Employee
  has_many :drivers, through: :company, source: :employees, class_name: 'Driver'
  has_many :chefs, through: :company, source: :employees, class_name: 'Chef'
end
```

The SQL query it fires is

```
SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" INNER JOIN "companies" ON "employees"."company_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "employees"."type" IN ('Driver') AND "companies"."id" = 1
```

Not *exactly* the query you envision, but it works.

Comment: Thank you it works. I have found another solution. has_many :drivers, primary_key: :'company_id', foreign_key: :'company_id' this creates the query as what I expect